The base group of a wreath product of an abelian group by $ {\mathbb{Z}}$ is a characterstic subgroup
I've copied over this question from what I asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange, in the hope that some experts here can direct me to some relevant results.
Let $A$ be a finitely generated abelian group, and let $G = A \wr {\mathbb{Z}} $ be the standard wreath product. Let $B = \oplus_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ be the base group of this wreath product. I want to show that $B$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.
If $A$ is finite, this is clear as $B$ is the maximal torsion subgroup of $G$. If $A$ is infinite, my idea is to show that $B$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$, hence it is characteristic. I was wondering if there are any ways to see that $B$ is a characteristic subgroup, or if this has been studied before?
Any reference will be really appreciated.

I think this follows from Theorem 9.12 in Peter Neumann,
On the structure of standard wreath products of groups? https://eudml.org/doc/170273

Thank you for the reference.

You idea is the good one: it is quite strightforward to prove that $A^{(\mathbf{Z})}$ is indeed the Fitting subgroup of $A\wr\mathbf{Z}$. This is certainly easier than any approach that would consist in describing how automorphisms look like. The approach in P. Neumann's paper is much more complicated, but this is because he addresses much more general wreath products.

$B$ is the unique maximal abelian normal subgroup of the wreath product. Every abelian normal subgroup is contained in $B$.
